# singleton in multi document

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, singleton

i used to using singleton like that:

```
///.h
@interface ASMyController:NSViewController
+(id)myViewController;
@end
////.m
static ASMyController* singleton = nil;
@implementation ASMyController
+(id)myViewController
{
    if(nil == singleton)
    {
        singleton = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    }
    return singleton;
}
-(id)init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"test" bundle:xxxx];
    if(self)
    {
        ..............................
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

The singleton work well in non-document-base application.However, in document - base Application, each instance of app share the same static variable. In my first design, the singleton one and only in a app instance but not all app instances.

So is it mean that I should reconsider the design ? Or I can make the singleton to a dict. and I can use key to get a singleton of current instance? Or any other good idea for me?

I pray that my poor English will not trouble u..

Answer (score 0):

The very name of your method, `my...`, suggests something rather fundamental is being misunderstood - there is just one singleton shared by *everybody*, objects don't own their own copies of singletons.

A singleton is not a way to avoid a variable, it appears you might be trying to use `[ASMyController myViewController]` instead of an instance variable `self->myViewController` (often abbreviated to `myViewController`) or a property `self.myViewController`.

You probably need to look at something along the lines of:

```
@interface ASMyDocument : NSDocument
{
   ASMyContoller *myViewController;
}
```

However your original design suggests you should really review the relationships between/meanings of classes, instances, singletons, has-a, is-a etc.

Comment: I'm sorry for saying unclearly, please review the question again.

Comment: @illusion - yes, as your question now asks you should reconsider your design. You appear to be misunderstanding the purpose of a singleton. As far as I understand your case you will have multiple instances of your document class (I named it `ASMyDocument`) and each of these needs its own instance of your `ASMyController` class - see the code fragment in my answer. You do not need *any* singletons at all. In objected-oriented terminology each document `has-a` controller; if that does not make sense to you then you need to review the object-oriented programming model.